# A question about "that"

Tags: grammar

In the sentence below what is the role of "that"? could it be omitted?

> If parental chromosomes are normal, as in 75% of cases, the risk to
> further offspring is minimal, probably similar to **that** following a
> trisomic child at the same maternal age, and under 1% in younger
> women.

Comment: It appears to refer to "risk".

Comment: More specifically, it's a demonstrative determinative functioning as a fused determiner-head. It's understood as "that risk". The non-reduced version would contain "the" rather than "that": _probably similar to the risk following a trisomic child ..._. No, it can't be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

"That" refers to the *risk*. It could be written as:

> the risk to further offspring is minimal, probably similar to *the risk* following a trisomic child at the same maternal age

It should not be omitted, as it would sound odd.

> similar to following a trisomic child

Where are you following the child? Following it home? Why is following a child similar what we are talking about? You get the point.